# How to import JSON into SQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, json

I'm trying something new and could use some guidance.  I have a JSON file full of data that I would like to have imported into SQL 2016.  I can get the entire file into SQL but breaking it apart into a readable format is where I am stuck.  I'm new to SQL, so when reading articles on this subject I am struggling to comprehend.  The following query is what I've used to perform the initial import:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\tmp\test.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
```

Each row is populated but the values contain sub sections that I need to have expanded.  Here is the test data that I am using:

```
{
"site_id":123456,
"statusEnum":"fully_configured",
"status":"fully-configured",
"domain":"site.name.com",
"account_id":111111,
"acceleration_level":"standard",
"site_creation_date":1410815844000,
"ips":[
    "99.99.99.99"
],
"dns":[
    {
        "dns_record_name":"site.name.com",
        "set_type_to":"CNAME",
        "set_data_to":[
            "frgt.x.wafdns.net"
        ]
    }
],
"original_dns":[
    {
        "dns_record_name":"name.com",
        "set_type_to":"A",
        "set_data_to":[
            ""
        ]
    },
    {
        "dns_record_name":"site.name.com",
        "set_type_to":"A",
        "set_data_to":[
            "99.99.99.99"
        ]
    },
    {
        "dns_record_name":"site.name.com",
        "set_type_to":"CNAME",
        "set_data_to":[
            ""
        ]
    }
],
"warnings":[

],
"active":"active",
"additionalErrors":[

],
"display_name":"site.name.com",
"security":{
    "waf":{
        "rules":[
            {
                "action":"api.threats.action.block_ip",
                "action_text":"Block IP",
                "id":"api.threats.sql_injection",
                "name":"SQL Injection"
            },
            {
                "action":"api.threats.action.block_request",
                "action_text":"Block Request",
                "id":"api.threats.cross_site_scripting",
                "name":"Cross Site Scripting"
            },
            {
                "action":"api.threats.action.block_ip",
                "action_text":"Block IP",
                "id":"api.threats.illegal_resource_access",
                "name":"Illegal Resource Access"
            },
            {
                "block_bad_bots":true,
                "challenge_suspected_bots":true,
                "exceptions":[
                    {
                        "values":[
                            {
                                "ips":[
                                    "99.99.99.99"
                                ],
                                "id":"api.rule_exception_type.client_ip",
                                "name":"IP"
                            }
                        ],
                        "id":123456789
                    },
                    {
                        "values":[
                            {
                                "ips":[
                                    "99.99.99.99"
                                ],
                                "id":"api.rule_exception_type.client_ip",
                                "name":"IP"
                            }
                        ],
                        "id":987654321
                    }
                ],
                "id":"api.threats.bot_access_control",
                "name":"Bot Access Control"
            },
            {
                "activation_mode":"api.threats.ddos.activation_mode.auto",
                "activation_mode_text":"Auto",
                "ddos_traffic_threshold":1000,
                "id":"api.threats.ddos",
                "name":"DDoS"
            },
            {
                "action":"api.threats.action.quarantine_url",
                "action_text":"Auto-Quarantine",
                "id":"api.threats.backdoor",
                "name":"Backdoor Protect"
            },
            {
                "action":"api.threats.action.block_ip",
                "action_text":"Block IP",
                "id":"api.threats.remote_file_inclusion",
                "name":"Remote File Inclusion"
            },
            {
                "action":"api.threats.action.disabled",
                "action_text":"Ignore",
                "id":"api.threats.customRule",
                "name":"wafRules"
            }
        ]
    },
    "acls":{
        "rules":[
            {
                "ips":[
                    "99.99.99.99"
                ],
                "id":"api.acl.whitelisted_ips",
                "name":"Visitors from whitelisted IPs"
            },
            {
                "geo":{
                    "countries":[
                        "BR",
                        "CN",
                        "DE",
                        "ES",
                        "GB",
                        "HK",
                        "IR",
                        "IT",
                        "KP",
                        "KR",
                        "KZ",
                        "NL",
                        "PL",
                        "RO",
                        "RU",
                        "TR",
                        "TW",
                        "UA"
                    ]
                },
                "id":"api.acl.blacklisted_countries",
                "name":"Visitors from blacklisted Countries"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"sealLocation":{
    "id":"api.seal_location.none",
    "name":"No seal "
},
"ssl":{
    "origin_server":{
        "detected":true,
        "detectionStatus":"ok"
    },
    "generated_certificate":{
        "ca":"GS",
        "validation_method":"email",
        "validation_data":"administrator@site.name.com",
        "san":[
            "*.site.name.com"
        ],
        "validation_status":"done"
    }
},
"siteDualFactorSettings":{
    "specificUsers":[

    ],
    "enabled":false,
    "customAreas":[

    ],
    "allowAllUsers":true,
    "shouldSuggestApplicatons":true,
    "allowedMedia":[
        "ga",
        "sms"
    ],
    "shouldSendLoginNotifications":true,
    "version":0
},
"login_protect":{
    "enabled":false,
    "specific_users_list":[

    ],
    "send_lp_notifications":true,
    "allow_all_users":true,
    "authentication_methods":[
        "ga",
        "sms"
    ],
    "urls":[

    ],
    "url_patterns":[

    ]
},
"performance_configuration":{
    "advanced_caching_rules":{
        "never_cache_resources":[

        ],
        "always_cache_resources":[

        ]
    },
    "acceleration_level":"standard",
    "async_validation":true,
    "minify_javascript":true,
    "minify_css":true,
    "minify_static_html":true,
    "compress_jepg":true,
    "progressive_image_rendering":false,
    "aggressive_compression":false,
    "compress_png":true,
    "on_the_fly_compression":true,
    "tcp_pre_pooling":true,
    "comply_no_cache":false,
    "comply_vary":false,
    "use_shortest_caching":false,
    "perfer_last_modified":false,
    "accelerate_https":false,
    "disable_client_side_caching":false,
    "cache300x":false,
    "cache_headers":[

    ]
},
"extended_ddos":1000,
"res":0,
"res_message":"OK",
"debug_info":{
    "id-info":"1234"
}
}
```

I know enough about SQL to know that I am going to have to have multiple tables for these subsections.  How do I select these subsections to expand them out into their own tables?  If I am not clear on the explanation or the question, please comment and I will do my best to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully import my JSON data into a SQL data base using the following code:

```
###Getting the list of Site_IDs
$param1 = @{account_id='####';api_id='######'; api_key='asdfjklmnopqrstuvwxyz';page_size='1000'}
$sitelist = Invoke-WebRequest https://my.website.com/api/prov/v1/sites/list -Method Post -Body $param1
$sitelist = $sitelist.content
$sitelist = $sitelist | convertfrom-json
$sitelist = $sitelist.sites
$sites = $sitelist | select -ExpandProperty Site_ID

###Setting the ConnectionString for the SQL Server and Database       
$server = 'servername\sqlinstance'
$database = 'databasename'
$connstring = "server = $server; database = $database; trusted_connection = true;"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connstring
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 60
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd.CommandText = $query
$cmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Site_ID",[Data.SQLDBType]::BigInt,20))) | Out-Null
$cmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@JSON_Source",[Data.SQLDBType]::NVARCHAR))) | Out-Null

###Setting the SQL Query to Insert the Site Data
$query = @"
INSERT INTO dbo.WebsiteSourceData (Site_ID,JSON_Source)
Values (@Site_ID, @JSON_Source);
"@

###Opening the SQL Connection
Try{
    $conn.Open()    

    ###Looping through each site to get it's configuration and then inserting that data to SQL
    ForEach($site in $sites){
        $param2 = @{api_id='#####';api_key='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';site_id="$site"}
        $status = Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://my.website.com/api/prov/v1/sites/status -Method Post -Body $param2 
        $content = $status.Content        
        $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $adapter.SelectCommand = $cmd        
        $cmd.Parameters[0].Value = $site
        $cmd.Parameters[1].Value = $content
        $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $adapter.Fill($dataset)
        }#ForEach($site in $sites)
    }#Try
Catch{ 
    Write-Host "Exception thrown : $($error[0].exception.message)"
    }#Catch
Finally{
    $conn.Close()
    }#Finally
```

From there, using the extremely helpful advice from this thread: [How to shred JSON data from within a SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459891/how-can-i-shred-json-data-already-in-a-sql-database) I was able to access and parse out the data into separate tables.