# How can I "shred" JSON data already in a SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, json

I have successfully imported a JSON file into a SQL 2016 database and I am now attempting to parse that data so that I can populate a table for each of the fields in the column that is holding the JSON data.  I am no DBA and it took me a couple of days to figure out how to successfully import this data.  I need to know how to accomplish this using SQL.  I am not certain what other information I need to provide here, so if anything else is needed, let me know and I will provide that info.

The table name is dbo.IncapsulaSourceData. This table has 5 columns: Site_ID, JSON_Source, Processed, Date_inserted, Date_processed.

Here is a sample of the JSON data that is being stored in the JSON_Source column:

```
{
"site_id":123456,
"statusEnum":"fully_configured",
"status":"fully-configured",
"domain":"site.name.com",
"account_id":111111,
"acceleration_level":"standard",
"site_creation_date":1410815844000,
"ips":[
"99.99.99.99"
],
"dns":[
{
    "dns_record_name":"site.name.com",
    "set_type_to":"CNAME",
    "set_data_to":[
        "frgt.x.wafdns.net"
    ]
}
],
"original_dns":[
{
    "dns_record_name":"name.com",
    "set_type_to":"A",
    "set_data_to":[
        ""
    ]
},
{
    "dns_record_name":"site.name.com",
    "set_type_to":"A",
    "set_data_to":[
        "99.99.99.99"
    ]
},
{
    "dns_record_name":"site.name.com",
    "set_type_to":"CNAME",
    "set_data_to":[
        ""
    ]
}
],
"warnings":[

],
"active":"active",
"additionalErrors":[

],
"display_name":"site.name.com",
"security":{
"waf":{
    "rules":[
        {
            "action":"api.threats.action.block_ip",
            "action_text":"Block IP",
            "id":"api.threats.sql_injection",
            "name":"SQL Injection"
        },
        {
            "action":"api.threats.action.block_request",
            "action_text":"Block Request",
            "id":"api.threats.cross_site_scripting",
            "name":"Cross Site Scripting"
        },
        {
            "action":"api.threats.action.block_ip",
            "action_text":"Block IP",
            "id":"api.threats.illegal_resource_access",
            "name":"Illegal Resource Access"
        },
        {
            "block_bad_bots":true,
            "challenge_suspected_bots":true,
            "exceptions":[
                {
                    "values":[
                        {
                            "ips":[
                                "99.99.99.99"
                            ],
                            "id":"api.rule_exception_type.client_ip",
                            "name":"IP"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id":123456789
                },
                {
                    "values":[
                        {
                            "ips":[
                                "99.99.99.99"
                            ],
                            "id":"api.rule_exception_type.client_ip",
                            "name":"IP"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id":987654321
                }
            ],
            "id":"api.threats.bot_access_control",
            "name":"Bot Access Control"
        },
        {
            "activation_mode":"api.threats.ddos.activation_mode.auto",
            "activation_mode_text":"Auto",
            "ddos_traffic_threshold":1000,
            "id":"api.threats.ddos",
            "name":"DDoS"
        },
        {
            "action":"api.threats.action.quarantine_url",
            "action_text":"Auto-Quarantine",
            "id":"api.threats.backdoor",
            "name":"Backdoor Protect"
        },
        {
            "action":"api.threats.action.block_ip",
            "action_text":"Block IP",
            "id":"api.threats.remote_file_inclusion",
            "name":"Remote File Inclusion"
        },
        {
            "action":"api.threats.action.disabled",
            "action_text":"Ignore",
            "id":"api.threats.customRule",
            "name":"wafRules"
        }
    ]
},
"acls":{
    "rules":[
        {
            "ips":[
                "99.99.99.99"
            ],
            "id":"api.acl.whitelisted_ips",
            "name":"Visitors from whitelisted IPs"
        },
        {
            "geo":{
                "countries":[
                    "BR",                        
                    "NL",
                    "PL",
                    "RO",
                    "RU",
                    "TR",
                    "TW",
                    "UA"
                ]
            },
            "id":"api.acl.blacklisted_countries",
            "name":"Visitors from blacklisted Countries"
        }
    ]
}
},
"sealLocation":{
"id":"api.seal_location.none",
"name":"No seal "
},
"ssl":{
"origin_server":{
    "detected":true,
    "detectionStatus":"ok"
},
"generated_certificate":{
    "ca":"GS",
    "validation_method":"email",
    "validation_data":"administrator@site.name.com",
    "san":[
        "*.site.name.com"
    ],
    "validation_status":"done"
}
},
"siteDualFactorSettings":{
"specificUsers":[

],
"enabled":false,
"customAreas":[

],
"allowAllUsers":true,
"shouldSuggestApplicatons":true,
"allowedMedia":[
    "ga",
    "sms"
],
"shouldSendLoginNotifications":true,
"version":0
},
"login_protect":{
"enabled":false,
"specific_users_list":[

],
"send_lp_notifications":true,
"allow_all_users":true,
"authentication_methods":[
    "ga",
    "sms"
],
"urls":[

],
"url_patterns":[

]
},
"performance_configuration":{
"advanced_caching_rules":{
    "never_cache_resources":[

    ],
    "always_cache_resources":[

    ]
},
"acceleration_level":"standard",
"async_validation":true,
"minify_javascript":true,
"minify_css":true,
"minify_static_html":true,
"compress_jepg":true,
"progressive_image_rendering":false,
"aggressive_compression":false,
"compress_png":true,
"on_the_fly_compression":true,
"tcp_pre_pooling":true,
"comply_no_cache":false,
"comply_vary":false,
"use_shortest_caching":false,
"perfer_last_modified":false,
"accelerate_https":false,
"disable_client_side_caching":false,
"cache300x":false,
"cache_headers":[

]
},
"extended_ddos":1000,
"res":0,
"res_message":"OK",
"debug_info":{
"id-info":"1234"
}
}
```

Comment: I believe OPENJSON and associated functions are what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server the only catch is you need SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @JacobH Yes, I do need to use OPENJSON and I am using SQL Server 2016.  The problem is that I don't know how to properly code the syntax needed to perform this task.

Comment: Well start with providing us at least your table and column structure and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JacobH The database name is Incapsula.  The table name is dbo.IncapsulaSourceData.  This table has 5 columns:
Site_ID, JSON_Source, Processed, Date_inserted, Date_processed

The column JSON_Source is where the JSON file is being imported to.  It is here that I need to parse the data and separate into other tables.

Comment: Start with this `DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max)
SET @json = (SELECT JSON_Source FROM IncapsulaSourceData)
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)` and see what you get for results.

Comment: @JacobH `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: How many rows do you have? This will only parse 1 JSON dataset at a time. You may need to go row by row, at least until you get comfortable using the query. Use (SELECT TOP 1 JSON_Source FROM IncapsulaSourceData) to select just the top 1 row.

Comment: @JacobH There are currently 95 rows.

Comment: You will probably need some dynamic sql or a while query to do them all. But seriously start small with 1 row and get comfortable with the query, then you can expand on it.

Comment: @JacobH Perfect.  That worked and I see my data in separate rows.  I will work on looping through each of the rows in the database.  Can you tell me how I can expand the value for a row that has multiple values?

Comment: That's about the extent of my knowledge. Not a JSON person unfortunately. There are a few more JSON functions that I am sure will do the trick, but you'll have to find a more experienced JSON user or read the docs :)

Comment: @JacobH No problem.  Thank you for your help.  I will continue to research now that I have a good starting point.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea of how to parse top level and second level data from json:

```
select top 100
    ids.Site_ID, 
    ids.JSON_Source,
    ids.Processed,
    ids.Date_inserted,
    ids.Date_processed,
    x.site_id,
    x.statusEnum,
    x.[status],
    x.[domain],
    x.account_id,
    x.acceleration_level,
    x.site_creation_date,
    x.ips as ipsJson,
    x.dns as dnsJson,
    ipsArr.key as ipKey,
    ipsArr.value as [ip],
    dnsArr.dns_record_name,
    dnsArr.set_type_to,
    dnsArr.set_data_to
from IncapsulaSourceData isd
outer apply openjson(isd.JSON_Source)
    with (
        site_id bigint,
        statusEnum nvarchar(max),
        [status] nvarchar(max),
        [domain] nvarchar(max),
        account_id bigint,
        acceleration_level nvarchar(max),
        site_creation_date bigint,
        ips nvarchar(max) as json,
        dns nvarchar(max) as json
        -- JSON_Source contains only 1 object, so original rows 
        -- won't be duplicated. But this object contains some arrays 
        -- e.g. ips and dns. We don't parse them in this apply so no problem here
    ) as x
outer apply openjson(isd.JSON_Source, '$.ips') as ipsArr
-- here we parse arrays (ips above and dns below). 
-- For some ids.row if there're 10 ipsArr values then in output 
-- there'll be 10 rows <ids.row, ipsArr.value>.
-- I mean maybe you want to parse them in another query at all.
outer apply openjson(isd.JSON_Source, '$.dns')
    with (
        dns_record_name nvarchar(max),
        set_type_to nvarchar(max),
        set_data_to nvarchar(max) as json
    ) as dnsArr
-- other outer applies here
```

Sorry, wrote without checking in IDE, maybe made some mistakes.

p.s. maaaaaan, your inconsistent naming makes me cry!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't create these naming conventions.  This data came from a web request made utilizing an API call.  Thank you so much for the information that you provided.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help ya :)